# Insert a value in clonable form text field using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a text field called. It can be cloned. Also there is a link available to select the value.

I have created a js fiddle to show you.

Full page view:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZpEK9/embedded/result/

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/ZpEK9/

As you can see there, if you click the "select a name" link it will popup a window. That window has names and a link to select the name.

I want to insert that name in the text field when the user clock "insert name" link. Can anyone help me with jquery code..

PS: Form fields are clonable.

This is how my code look like..

```
<form>
    <div class="control-group success">

  <div class="controls">
      <p class="clone"><input type="text" name="name[]"><span class="help-inline"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Select a name</a></span></p>
    <span class="help-inline"><a href="#" class="add" rel=".clone">Add More</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
           <div class="row-fluid">
            <ul class="thumbnails">
              <li class="span4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                  <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Sam</h3>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Insert name</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="span4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                  <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Linda</h3>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Insert name</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="span4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                  <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Lucy</h3>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Insert name</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="span4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                  <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Jenifer</h3>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Insert name</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          </div>​
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your JSFiddle here with a working solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/jg5C7/3/

Added 'select-name' class to the link:

```
    <span class="help-inline">
        <a class="select-name" href="#myModal">Select a name</a>
    </span>
```

Added bindings to the link:

```
    $('a.select-name').click(function() {
        $('#myModal').data('current-input', $(this));
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });

    $('#myModal .btn').click(function() {
        $('#myModal').data('current-input').closest('p').find(':text').val($(this).data('value'));
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    });
```

Added data-value attributes to the buttons, example:

```
    <p><a href="#" data-value="Sam" class="btn btn-primary">Insert name</a></p>
```

Because you're using plugins to do some magic, it's a bit less of an elegant solution but really the only change to what you're currently doing is I'm manually triggering the modal open / close so that I can hook onto the click event of the "Select Name" link.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I've changed the input name and added `option` class to each `<a>`.

```
$('a.option').on('click', function() {
  $('input[name="name"]').val($(this).parent().parent().find('h3').text())
  $('.modal').toggle()
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZpEK9/1/)

Comment: Hello mate, thanks. But clone function not working in your fiddle, I added clone function in your fiddle. But the same value get filled in all form fields. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/ZpEK9/2/

Comment: I mean duplication... Goto this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZpEK9/ and click the "Add more" link.. The text field will be duplicated/cloned

Comment: This method does not work because the inputs are added dynamically and the Select Name link needs to be bound to it's sibling input. Your example would set all of the input values to the selected name.

Comment: True, didn't pay attention to the cloning.